# how to share docker container volume with other team members

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a container with postgres ( for dev purposes), on that container i did some manual changes over the database that i wish to share with other team members,

the following yml file is committed to git, i wish to commit the volume it self so all other team members could compose the container using the data i manually added. so each team member will compose the container with the data i pre-created.

**is there a clean way to share the volume with other team members ??**
we all use macOS

ideally i want to commit the volume to git and define a fixed volume file but not sure how to do that.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  postgres-server:
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env.dev
    environment:
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    volumes:
      - postgres-server:/var/lib/postgres-server/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"


  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:6.5
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env.dev
    environment:
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 80
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin



volumes:
  postgres-server:
  pgadmin:
```

Comment: One way is to create an image based on the postgres image, and put a database dump inside the directory `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. That will automatically import the database on first startup. See https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md#initialization-scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not really how volumes work. They are not meant to be source-controlled in git. You could make a DB dump and source control that.

For example, you could use [pgdump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgdump.html) but there are other tools that can do this too.

```
pg_dump --schema-only mydb > db.sql
```

You can then configure your compose file to mount this dump file when starting. If there is no volume with data, Postgres will use the dump to set up the DB.

```yaml
services:
  postgres-server:
    volumes:
      - ./db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db.sql
      - postgres-server:/var/lib/postgres-server/data
```

But be careful that there is no confidential data inside this dump file. That's why in the above example, I have dumped only the schema. So no actual data is source controlled. Data itself isn't meant for git either.

Answer (score 0):

You could use tar to backup the volume content. From that tar archive you could then create a new container.

If you want to do so, have a look at
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68230268/4222206
It tars/untars the data, however you may want to have a step inbetween to share the tar ball with your team members.